# Can blocks being exist and displayed without being stored in blocks table?

Tags: blocks, dashboard

I'm wondering what could be the problem.

When I queried the homebox_default table , it showed bids with 1950
1387
1382
953
958
1916

but when queried in the blocks table for these blocks with these bids are not existant there was no blocks with those ids. But when I see the homebox/1 page it shows page with blocks. How is that possible?

Comment: Yep, they could exist in cache, for example. Can't really comment on your specific situation without more details

Answer (score 0):

Homeblock is actually not storing the data in block, it is actually inserting the data in its own custom table, like homeblock_users.

```
  $data = new stdClass();
  $data->uid = $user->uid;
  $data->name = $page->name;
  $data->settings = $blocks;
  drupal_write_record('homebox_users', $data);
```

It is saving block data in hoemblock_users table. It is creating only one Block i.e. Homebox custom block.

```
homebox_prepare_block
```

Above is the function through which dynamic block is created for a page, and all the variables are assigned to it.